# costmap_2d doesn't fit environment map size

Tags: navigation, rviz, ros-melodic, costmap-2d

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using ROS Melodic on Ubuntu 18.04

I have generated a map of an environment with **gmapping** and now I'm trying to make my **Turtlebot3** navigate it autonomously via the **move_base** package. This is my .yaml file of the map:

```
image: house.pgm
resolution: 0.050000
origin: [-10.000000, -10.000000, 0.000000]
negate: 0
occupied_thresh: 0.65
free_thresh: 0.196
```

then I added a line in my `.launch` file to run the move_base node, this is it:

```
<node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" name="move_base" / >
```

Sadly this wasn't enough, because the costmap I was getting wasn't transformed correctly "above" the environment map, it was offset at the top-left-most corner. Moreover, it wasn't scaled properly. Fairly easy to fix, I thought, because I didn't specify the **origin** and the **width/height** of the map. Just a matter of parameters:

```
<param name="global_costmap/origin_x" value="-10" />
<param name="global_costmap/origin_y" value="-10" />
<param name="global_costmap/height" value="19" />
<param name="global_costmap/width" value="19" />
```

The `origin_x` and `origin_y` were copied from the `.yaml` file, but then I had to do some tweaks in order to scale the costmap correctly, because it was 20x bigger than the map (*why this, I don't know and hope someone can help me through*.)
Via **Rviz**, I found out that my map was 384x384, dividing by 20 gave 19.2, which rounded down is the value you can see above as `global_costmap/height` and `global_costmap/width`. This way, at least, they overlap for the most part, but the result is as expected: the environment map is larger by a small amount.
[image: image description] **Light gray**: costmap, **dark gray**: environment map, **black**: background

Moreover, the costmap doesn't get **rendered** on Rviz, meaning I cannot see darker areas along the obstacles, [like this](http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=costmap_rviz.png), and the footprint of the Turtlebot3 is way larger than expected.

#### Edit no.1

> the footprint of the Turtlebot3 is way larger than expected

Simply because I forgot to add this parameter to the move_base node:

```
<rosparam file="$(find turtlebot3_navigation)/param/costmap_common_params_$(arg model).yaml" command="load" />
```

This way, I can retrieve the correct footprint of whatever model of Turtlebot I'm deploying.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/335748/costmap_2d-doesn%27t-fit-environment-map-size/) by [davidem](https://answers.ros.org/users/47142/davidem/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2019-10-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are dozens of parameters that need to be set to run move_base - I'd suggest looking at the pre-configured [turtlebot_navigation](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_navigation) package rather than trying to configure yourself. If you really want to configure yourself, see [the tutorial on the wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/Navigation%20Tuning%20Guide)

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2019-10-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [davidem](https://answers.ros.org/users/47142/davidem/) on 2019-10-20**:
Thanks for the sources, I'll give a look. I am not a copy-paste guy, so I prefer to follow instructions and read docs rather than using a pre-configured thing. Sadly, docs aren't very detailed on parameters and tweaks, while tutorials are scarse...

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2019-10-20**:
I would think of it less as copy and paste and more as the vendor having provided a default configuration that you can then tweak. You didn’t decide to write your own drivers for the platform for instance, no need to start entirely from scratch on the navigation config either. Setting up move_base from scratch is a very advanced topic.

**Comment by [davidem](https://answers.ros.org/users/47142/davidem/) on 2019-10-20**:
Lesson learned. Thanks